# How to "concatenate" and define a variable at the same time

Tags: r

I got this two data frames:

```
variables = tibble(x = "A", y = "P")
description = tibble(x = "Area", y = "Perimeter")
```

And i want to reach this:

```
list(A = "Area", P = "Perimeter")
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Are the columns are always in the same order? Couldn't something like `tibble(y = "A", x = "P")` possible? If so, I would go with `var <- as.list(variables) ; des <- as.list(description) ; setNames(des, var[names(des)])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l <- as.list(description)
names(l) <- variables
```

**Output**

```
> l
$A
[1] "Area"

$P
[1] "Perimeter"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can `unlist` the dataframe and create a named list using `setNames` :

```
setNames(as.list(unlist(description)), unlist(variables))

#$A
#[1] "Area"

#$P
#[1] "Perimeter"
```

You can rename the dataframe column names instead of individual values as suggested by @Darren Tsai which make it shorter and simple.

```
as.list(setNames(description, variables))
```

Comment: To be more simplified, `as.list(setNames(description, variables))` also works.

Comment: This incredible works! This apparent to be a simple problem, but I'm using this with BERT attribution function. Ty a lot!

Comment: Some might find a different order of operations more intuitive: `setNames(as.list(description), variables))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unclass`

```
setNames(unclass(description), variables)
#$A
#[1] "Area"

#$P
#[1] "Perimeter"
```